# How many data attributes there are in Bootstrap? What they do and what are the possible values for them?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching the web about the data attributes in bootstrap, like data-toggle, data-trigger, data-ride.... but I can't seem to find a list about all of them.

I'm also wondering what are the possible values for them, for example: data-trigger="focus". Instead of focus, it could be hover, and many others. Where can I find a list about all of them? Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## This is the complete reference of data attributes for bootstrap 3

> The reference is based on the data exists in the bootstrap 3 manual page, divided by the different modules.

### Modals

`data-toggle="modal"` - Triggers click to open a modal dialog referenced by `data-target="element"`
`data-target="target-element"` - The element that the modal should open (can be #id or .class)
`data-dismiss="modal"` - Triggers close of the modal on click

### Dropdowns

`data-toggle="dropdown"` - Triggers click to open a drop-down
`data-target="#"` - Only exists to help when use the dropdown on link to prevent url change

### ScrollSpy

`data-spy="scroll"` - Triggers the SpyScroll on the element (usually goes to `<body>`
`data-target="target-element"` - The element that the scroll-spy should by applied to
`data-offset="X"` - X represents the number of pixels from top when calculating position of scroll

### Togglable tabs

`data-toggle="tab"` - Triggers click to open the relevant tab referenced by `data-target="element"`
`data-toggle="pill"` - Same as `tab` but for pill-styling
`data-target="target-element"` - The element that the modal should open (can be #id or .class)

> Note that it's also possible to use `href="#target-element-id"` and not only `data-target` here

### Tooltips

`data-toggle="tooltip"` - Triggers adding a tooltip to the element

> The tooltip has many data attributes, so this is only the list of all of them with the available values. Complete explanation of all of them is in [this link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options).

`data-animation`
`data-container`
`data-delay`
`data-html`
`data-placement`
`data-selector`
`data-template`
`data-title`
`data-trigger`
`data-viewport`

### Popovers

`data-toggle="popover"` - Triggers click to open a popover

> The popovers has many data attributes, so this is only the list of all of them with the available values. Complete explanation of all of them is in [this link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options).

`data-animation`
`data-container`
`data-content`
`data-delay`
`data-html`
`data-placement`
`data-selector`
`data-template`
`data-title`
`data-trigger`
`data-viewport`

### Alert messages

`data-dismiss="alert"` - Triggers click to close the alert box created by bootstrap

### Buttons

`data-loading-text="Loading..."` - Show a text while loading (**note that it's deprecated**)
`data-toggle="button"` - *note the singular* Makes a button single toggle-button
`data-toggle="buttons"` - *note the plural* Makes a group of buttons a toggle-buttons
`data-complete-text="Finished"` - Text to change on button when the method `complete` is called

### Collapse

`data-toggle="collapse"` - Triggers click to collapse the referenced element
`data-target="element"` - The referenced element
`data-parent="element"` - The parent element, used for accordion-style collapsing

### Carousel

`data-ride="carousel"` - Triggers a slide-show (carousel) on the container
`data-target="element"` - The referenced carousel element that `this` element is part of
`data-slide-to="X"` - X is the number of the `next` slide
`data-slide="prev|next"` - Triggers click to toggle the carousel to the prev|next slide
`data-interval="X"` - The amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an item
`data-pause="hover"` - Pause the cycling on mouse over
`data-wrap="true"` - Whether the carousel should cycle continuously or have hard stops
`data-keyboard="true"` - Whether the carousel should react to keyboard events

### Affix

`data-spy="affix"` - Triggers affix (emulating the sticky positioning effect)
`data-offset-top="X"` - Number of pixels to offset the element from top
`data-offset-bottom="X"` - Number of pixels to offset the element from bottom

Comment: thank you very much, thats exactly what I was looking for!